# unable to convert received jsonp data to make source of datatable in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, datatables, jsonp

My jquery fetches json data from server using jsonp. 
The received data is as below.

```
"d":"[{"id":28,"first_name":"Examiner","last_name":"Exam","phone_no":"9876543210","email":"examiner@gmail.com","address":"Nashik","username":"examiner","password":"examiner","user_type":"examiner ","active":true},{"id":5,"first_name":"Jeevan","last_name":"Jadhav","phone_no":"9876543210","email":"jeevan@gmail.com","address":"nashik","username":"jeevan","password":"jeevan","user_type":"examiner ","active":true},{"id":40,"first_name":"Niraj","last_name":"Borwal","phone_no":"3453453450","email":"niraj@pointmatrix.com","address":"Nashik","username":"niraj","password":"niraj","user_type":"examiner ","active":true},{"id":26,"first_name":"sumit","last_name":"mogare","phone_no":"8675456876","email":"sumit1@gmail.com","address":"Nashik","username":"sumit","password":"mogare","user_type":"examiner ","active":true},{"id":53,"first_name":"aaa","last_name":"aaa","phone_no":"1234567890","email":"aaa@gmail.com","address":"aaa","username":"aaa","password":"aaa","user_type":"examiner ","active":true}]"
```

I need to convert this data to be suitable to add to datatable. But when I use `$.parseJSON(response)` jquery gives errors.
I think this data is string of objects.
 
How do I convert this data to json so that I may use it as "aaData" source for datatable.
my jquery code is as below

```
$('#btnClick').on("click", function () {
        debugger;
        var dt = 'type=' + $('#txt').val();
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: "http://localhost:6168/WcfService.svc/getData",
            type: "POST",
            jsonpCallback: "callback",
            data: dt,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                debugger;
                fillTable(response);
                console.log(response);
                // var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
                var dat = response;
                var data = dat.split(':');
                console.log(data);
                // var parsed = $.parseJSON('[' + response + ']');
                // var dt = $.parseJSON(parsed);
                //console.log(parsed);
                $('#text').text("you entered : " + response);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

and fillTable function is as below

```
function fillTable(resp) {
        $('[id*="mytable"]').DataTable({
            "aaData": resp,
            "aoColumns": [
        { "d": "id" },
        { "d": "first_name" },
        { "d": "last_name" },
        { "d": "phone_no" },
        { "d": "email" },
        { "d": "address" },
        { "d": "username" },
        { "d": "password" },
        { "d": "user_type" },
        { "d": "isActive" },
        ]
        });
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you're returning JSONP? That looks a lot more like JSON - although it's not valid - and they are not interchangeable. Seeing the error would also help here

Comment: I am not sure whether it is jsonp or json format, this is what I am receiving after serializing System.Data.Datatable using Newtonsoft.json's JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt); method.

Comment: This "JSON" is by no mean parseable.  The only way to solve this is some clever regex removing the spoiling quotes, and after that envelope the whole thing in {...} and parse it. I suggest you correct the backend to pass valid, parseable JSON.

Comment: It looks like a json object is assigned to a property `d` and then the whole lot is returned as json. or something.  With a few amendments it can be made to work client-side: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/1tvygqc6/)

Comment: @davidkonrad Yes I will definitely try to remove the spoiling quote at backend.

Comment: @markpsmith Thanks for the jsfiddle. It has given me an idea to process data in backend. Will surely post an answer after success.